# 'future_to_publish' hook not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to save data to a file when a scheduled post is published. I tried to do this using the hooks 'future_to_publish', 'publish_future_post', 'transition_post_status' - none of them worked for me. I experimented with changing the priority of the hooks - didn't work either.

This is my code:

```
<?php
function savePostData( $ID ) {
$wpRootPath     = get_home_path();
$postsDataPath  =  $wpRootPath . 'test.txt';
$handle = fopen( $postsDataPath, "w" );
fwrite( $handle, $ID );
fclose( $handle ); 
}
add_action( 'future_to_publish', 'savePostData', 10, 1 );
?>
```

When attaching the same function to the following hooks everything works:

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'savePostData', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'pending_to_publish', 'savePostData', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'draft_to_publish', 'savePostData' );
```

I read there is some problem with the is_admin() function interfering with the wordpress cron job, but, still, I cannot get this to work.

Comment: Is the function being called?

Comment: no, I don't think so, the function is not executed at all

Comment: You might insert some debug code, such as `$logdata = "\n" . date("D M d, Y G:i") . " - savePostData called \n";
$logdata .= "\nID : " . print_r($ID, true);
file_put_contents ( '/path/to/somewhere/with/write/file/permissions/savePostData.log' , $logdata , FILE_APPEND);`

Comment: This was a great idea! So, it turns out $ID is an array and I have no problem to print any of its elements to the file in the way you suggested. However, when I try to write to a file with `$handle = fopen( $postsDataPath, "w" ); fwrite( $handle, $ID->ID ); fclose( $handle );` As I told you, I don't have this problem with the other hooks...

Comment: OK. But if $ID is an array, what is $ID->ID ? Your next debugging step is probably to use `try` and use the $logdata to confirm what the exception is throwing.

Comment: $ID holds the WP_Post Object (https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) , your suggestion helped me realize the hook is actually called and the problem is elsewhere. Obviously, '$wpRootPath     = get_home_path(); ' worked when publishing post immediately, but not when scheduling a future post

Comment: No problem, it's an object and not an array ;-) if this fixed it, why not write your own answer so people can see or mark it

Comment: $ID is an object, correct :D  thanks once again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out when a post is published with cron, 'publish_post' hook is also executed and I didn't need to use it together with the 'future_to_publish' hook.

The problem with both hooks, however, was that for some reason get_home_path(); does not work in the same way as when the post is published immediately from admin panel, so using the exact path to my file solved the problem.